# How to tell when a user is making a tag vs a commit in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, tags, hook, commit

I have a hook written for Mercurial. It uses the pretxncommit to make sure that the user includes an 'issue number' in their commit message. But sometimes the user may use the 'hg tag' command instead of commit. In this case the user does not need to input an issue number.

How can I tell when the user is making a tag instead of a commit??? Here are a couple places I have searched for the answer but am I missing something or does the documentation just not go that far in depth.
https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MercurialApi
http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I tell when the user is making a tag instead of a commit???

- Making tag is commit
- Clean tagging commit affect only .hgtags file (and add one line to this file)

HTH

Comment: Ok thanks. But is it possible to tell when a user is using the 'hg tag' command versus the 'hg commit' command?

Comment: @user2137668 - user **always** use commit command, but - sometimes it's tagging-commit, sometimes - conent-commit. If commit-files list containt only `.hgtags` you can consider previous action as making tag (**if tag can't be added** to repository with pulling external repository)

Comment: So even when you use the 'hg tag' command, it is still considered a commit?

Comment: @user2137668 - `hg tag` just edit .hgtags behind the scene, you must to commit these changes in order to have it public

Comment: Ok got it. Any idea on how to tell when the user is making a tag? I'm using the Mercurial internal API in python .

Comment: @user2137668 - you can get timestamp of tag-child changeset

Comment: I didn't mean the actual time, but the act of making a tag commit. I think I found the solution which is to check if the .hgtags file is the only file that has changed.